# A Clojure program to classify files based on their filename

Tags: file-system, clojure

My first ever lines of Clojure and while the script seems to work as expected, I'm sure it's far from idiomatic Clojure. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bb

; =============================================================================
; PHOTOS.CLJ
; USE: ./photos.clj --src [src-dir] --dest [dest-dir]
; * Will copy photos from src-dir to dest-dir, grouped by desired photo format.
; * Indicate desired format by prefixing photo filenames with:
; * - m for small,
; * - v for large.
; * Will notify and fail if you accidentally have multiple photos with the same
; * filename in src-dir.
; =============================================================================

(require '[clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])
(use '[clojure.java.io :only (file, copy, make-parents)])

(defn parse-args [args]
  (let [options
          [["-s" "--src SOURCE-FOLDER" "Source folder"]
          ["-d" "--dest DESTINATION-FILDER" "Destination folder"]]
        args (:options (parse-opts args options))
       ]
    (do
      (assert (:src args) "--src must be specified")
      (assert (:dest args) "--dest must be specified")
      args)))

(def args (parse-args *command-line-args*))
    
(defn cathegory [name]
  (let [ch (first name)]  
    (cond
      (#{\m \M} ch) :small
      (#{\v \V} ch) :large
      :else (assert false (str "Unsupported cathegory: " ch)))))

(defn mark-seen [seen f]
  (do
    (assert (not (seen f)) (str "Duplicate file: " f))
    (conj seen f)))

(defn copy-file [seen f]
  (let [fname (.getName f)
        cat (cathegory fname)
        destf (file (str (:dest args) "/" (name cat) "/" fname))]
    (do
      (println cat (.getPath f))
      (make-parents destf)
      (copy f destf)
      (mark-seen seen fname))))

(def src-dir (file (:src args)))
(def src-files (filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq src-dir)))
(reduce copy-file #{} src-files)
```

Answer (score 3):

- `fn`, `defn` and `let` have implicit `do`, so you can remove it from `parse-args`, `mark-seen` and `copy-file`
- function `parse-args`: typo `"--dest DESTINATION-FILDER"` -> `"--dest DESTINATION-FOLDER"`
- function `cathegory` (typo in the name): you can use [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) here, [`case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case) will be better than `cond` and if you know that your `assert` has to fail, you can directly [`throw`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/throw) some error:

```
(defn category [[ch & _]]
  (case ch
    (\m \M) :small
    (\v \V) :large
    (throw (Exception. (str "Unsupported category: " ch)))))
```

- `src-dir` and `src-files` don't have to be global variables- I think you can just wrap your `reduce` in `let` and put these variables here:

```
(let [src-dir (file (:src args))
      src-files (filter #(.isFile %) (file-seq src-dir))]
  (reduce copy-file #{} src-files))
```

You can also use threading macro [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) and write something like this:

```
(->> (file (:src args))
     file-seq
     (filter #(.isFile %))
     (reduce copy-file #{}))
```

- function `copy-file`: function [`file`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/file) has a version with arguments `[parent child & more]`, so if every part of the path is a string, you don't have to join them with `"/"` manually:

```
(file (:dest args) (name category) fname)
```

By the way, Clojure has function [`cat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cat) and you're shadowing it with your variable `cat`.